# is it possible to develop a packet sniffer in android?

Tags: android, wifi

I am a computer science student, and need to do a final project in the communication field. 
I have experience with java but not with development to the android. 
My prof suggested I should develop a packet sniffer for the android os.
I know there are some packet sniffing programs, but I saw they require a root access.
Does that mean it can't be done via the regular SDK?
Does the wifi api (or any other api) allows you to get packets that are not aimed to your phone?
can you please tell me how it can be done? (or refer me to something helpul)

Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to sniff the packets of other programs then you will need root access. Otherwise the Android permission system will make sure that the only packets that you can see are the ones that are being sent to the packet sniffer directly.

Comment: 2 years later: finally, how did you proceed to develop your packet sniffer? I'm quite interesting in it too. See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14690650/1225328).

Comment: Hi sp00m, were you able to figure it out? You removed the link above. I am using a VpnService to do it, but I can only capture packets, I can't send them back. Please help.